# CakePHP: How to leave selected dropdown in layout on reload

Tags: jquery, html, cakephp, drop-down-menu

I have 2 dropdown menus in layout (country and city) and when user selects it he gets redirected to another part of the site. When new view renders the layout reloads and dropdown menu is left unselected again.

I was thinking to force selecting with jQuery but with 2 dropdowns is not so great. Maybe using session? The best would be not to render layout again but I don't think that is possible.. Anything else?

Comment: post whatever you have tried so far.

Comment: Session is not an option since you can't get form data without posting it to server.

Answer (score 1):

For my oppinion the best option is to store selected value in url. It will be looking like:

```
http://example.com/form/index?first=2&second=4
```

Here is some view example.

```
<?
echo $this->Form->create(false);

echo $this->Form->input('day', array(
        'class' => 'firstInput',
        'selected' => $this->request->query['first']
    ));

echo $this->Form->input('month', array(
        'class' => 'secondInput',
        'selected' => $this->request->query['second']
    ));

echo $this->Form->end('save');
?>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.firstInput, .secondInput').on('change', function(){
            var firstValue = $('.firstInput').val();
            var secondValue = $('.secondInput').val();

            window.location.replace('/form/index?first='+ firstValue +'&second='+secondValue)
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, I guess this is the best solution. However, is it possible to hide those information in URL from user? I really dislike showing that. Thanks

Comment: Sure, it is posible by submiting form each time user choses an option from dropdown menu. I have added another answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is possible to make it without url parameters by submiting form. Here is an idea.

In view:

```
<?
echo $this->Form->create(false);

echo $this->Form->input('day', array(
        'class' => 'firstInput'
    ));

echo $this->Form->input('month', array(
        'class' => 'secondInput'
    ));

echo $this->Form->end('save');
?>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.firstInput, .secondInput').on('change', function(){  
            $('form').submit();
        })
    });
</script>
```

In controller something like this:

```
public function add()
{
    //if both dropdowns are filled this is mean that we can save our form
    if(!empty($this->request->data['month']) && !empty($this->request->data['day'])){
        $this->Model->save($this->request->data);
    } 
    //else do nothing and render add page
}
```

I hope you got the idea.

Comment: I guess you meant without: 'selected' => $this->request->query['first'].